# It there some way for bulk upload of million files to Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have hundred millions of small files ~50KB. Is it possible to upload it to Azure Blob Storage as one or few pieces, to save time and money (not pay for each file as single Write Operation)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload zip file to azure blob then unzip it there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177893/how-to-upload-zip-file-to-azure-blob-then-unzip-it-there)

Comment: If I got my math right, assuming you zip all of your files together, the total size of the file will be approximately 4.65 TB (without compression) which is below 4.75 TB limit of a block blob, so I would say yes it is possible.

Comment: But when you want to access one of those files, you get to download the entire blob. Cool and Archive tiers charge for egress. And Hot is going to cost you more money. Who knows what your service provider will think about pulling down 4+TB of data. Make sure you're accounting for everything.

Comment: I want to have all my files unpacked on Azure Blob Storage, My question is about some way for bulk upload for millions of files.

Comment: As another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177893/how-to-upload-zip-file-to-azure-blob-then-unzip-it-there) mentioned that unzipping is not naively supported. Details please refer to the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/3388309-http-compression-support-for-azure-storage-service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently in the process of investigating the same thing. Based on some estimates I've produced it is going to take about 40 hours to upload our files to Azure storage.

The only alternative I've come across is to use the [Azure Import/Export Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-import-export-service), this involves physically sending your files on 1 or more HHDs and creating a job in Azure to transfer the files when the drive is plugged in at the data centre.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks like DHL will be able to transfer my millions of small files faster and cheaper, then I can do it by upload.